# Problems with functions.php! Error!

Tags: functions, errors, parse

Suddenly I got the message:

> **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in /home/spandabe/public_html/wp-content/themes/modularity-lite/functions.php
>   on line 72**

when opening my site [www.spandabel.dk](http://spandabel.dk)

I only changed things in header.php, not in functions.php! And now I cannot do anything before I get this right!

This is how my functions-php looks like:

```
    <?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Modularity
 */

$themecolors = array(
    'bg' => 'eeeeee',
    'border' => 'eeeeee',
    'text' => '111111',
    'link' => '000000',
    'url' => '000000'
);
$content_width = 950; // pixels

// Grab the theme options page
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/theme-options.php' );

// Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head
add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

// Add post thumbnail theme support
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150, true );

// Add a new image size
add_image_size( 'modularity-slideshow', 950, 425, true );

// Register nav menu locations
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'text_domain' ),
) );

// Get wp_page_menu() lookin' more like wp_nav_menu()
function modularity_page_menu_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_home'] = true;
    $args['menu_class'] = 'main-nav';
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'modularity_page_menu_args' );

// Give Modularity a custom background
add_custom_background();

// Allow custom colors to clear the background image
function modularity_custom_background_color() {
    if ( get_background_image() == '' && get_background_color() != '' ) { ?>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-image: none;
        }
        </style>            
    <?php }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'modularity_custom_background_color' );

// To use a sidebar, or not to use a sidebar, that is the question. This generates the appropriate class
function modularity_sidebar_class() {
    $options = get_option( 'modularity_theme_options' );

    if ( $options['sidebar'] == 1 ) {
        echo "15 colborder home";
    }
    else {
        echo "24 last";
    }   
}

// The header business begins here:

// No CSS, just IMG call
define('HEADER_TEXTCOLOR', '');
define('HEADER_IMAGE', '');
define('HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH', 950);
define('HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT', 250);
define( 'NO_HEADER_TEXT', true );

function modularity_admin_header_style() {
?>
<style type="text/css">
#headimg {
    height: <?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>px;
    width: <?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>px;
}

#headimg h1, #headimg #desc {
    display: none;
}

</style>
<?php
}

add_custom_image_header( '', 'modularity_admin_header_style' );
// and thus ends the header business

// Comments in the Modularity style
function modularity_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    switch ( $comment->comment_type ) :
        case '' :
    ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="comment-wrapper">
            <div class="comment-meta">
                <?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 75 ); ?>
                <div class="comment-author vcard">
                    <strong class="fn"><?php comment_author_link(); ?></strong>
                </div><!-- .comment-author .vcard -->
            </div>
            <div class="comment-entry">
                <?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) : ?>
                    <em><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'modularity' ); ?></em>
                    <br />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php comment_text(); ?>
                <p class="post-time">
                    <?php
                        /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
                        printf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'modularity' ), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time() ); ?></a><?php edit_comment_link( __( '(Edit)', 'modularity' ), ' ' );
                    ?>
                    <br />
                </p>
                <div class="reply">
                    <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .reply -->               
            </div>
    </div><!-- #comment-##  -->

    <?php
            break;
        case 'pingback'  :
        case 'trackback' :
    ?>
    <li class="pingback">
        <p><?php _e( 'Pingback:', 'modularity' ); ?> <?php comment_author_link(); ?><?php edit_comment_link( __('(Edit)', 'modularity'), ' ' ); ?></p>
    <?php
            break;
    endswitch;
}

// The Sidebar business
$options = get_option( 'modularity_theme_options' );
if ( $options['sidebar'] == 0 ) {
    $optional_description = __( 'The optional Modularity Lite sidebar is currently deactivated but can be activated from Appearance > Theme Options', 'modularity' );   
} else {
    $optional_description = ''; 
}

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar',
        'description' => $optional_description,
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="item %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="sub">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer 1',
        'id' => 'footer-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="item %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="sub">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer 2',
        'id' => 'footer-2',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="item %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="sub">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer 3',
        'id' => 'footer-3',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="item %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="sub">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer 4',
        'id' => 'footer-4',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="item %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="sub">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    )); 
}



// Load Base Javascripts
if (!is_admin()) add_action( 'init', 'load_base_js' );
function load_base_js( ) {

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    //wp_enqueue_script('jquerynav', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/nav.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('cycle', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.cycle.js', array('jquery'));
    //wp_enqueue_script('search', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/search.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

}

// Load Dom Ready Javascripts
function load_dom_ready_js() { ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery(function() {
                jQuery("#slideshow").cycle({
                    speed: '2500',
                    timeout: '500',
                    pause: 1
                });
            });
        });
    /* ]]> */
    </script>

<?php }
add_action('wp_head', 'load_dom_ready_js');
```

Does anybody have an idea what has happened??

Thanks in advance!

/ Anne

btw - the theme I'm using is Modularity Lite

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing `</style>` tag, and a `<?php }` for the function

```
function modularity_admin_header_style() { ?>
<style type="text/css">
#headimg {
    height: <?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>px;
    width: <?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>px;
}
</style>
<?php }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I tried with the </style> and <?php }, but it didn't make any difference.

I guess the line 72 is:

define('HEADER_TEXTCOLOR', '');

Comment: Edit your question and post all your functions.php code, otherwise is hard to know. What error message are you getting now ?

Comment: Okay, thanks for responding! this is really getting on my nerves now...  I'm still getting the error as above, no matter what I try. I now edited my question, adding the full functions.php

Comment: I got help via wordpress. The functions-php file postet here was incorrect, I found the current one using FileZilla, and found the error. 

But thanks anyway for your help, time and effort!!